# How to serialize Scala lambda for interop with Java method?

Tags: java, scala, serialization, scala-java-interop

I have a Java method which has a parameter of the interface type SerializablePredicate.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface SerializablePredicate<T> extends Predicate<T>, Serializable {}
```

What do I need to do in order to serialize a Scala lambda such as

```
(x:String) => println(x)
```

such that it will be compatible with the Java method.

Currently I am attempting to cast the lambda

```
class SomeClass[T](val p:(T=>Boolean)) extends SomeJavaClass[T](p.asInstanceOf[SerializablePredicate[T]]) {}
```

And this is the stack trace I'm getting...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Main$$anonfun$1 cannot be cast to io.cognitionbox.core.SerializablePredicate
at P.<init>(LogicJavaToScalaInterp.scala:11)
at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:9)
at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:3)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at Main$.main(Main.scala:3)
at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast **Scala** `Function` to **Java** `Functional`, they are **not the same thing**. but you can try to do it like:

```
class SomeClass[T](val p:(T=>Boolean)) extends SomeJavaClass[T]((t: T) => p.apply(t)) {}
```

In the above code: `(t: T) => p.apply(t)`, Creat a new `SerializablePredicate<T>` `Java` `FunctionalInterface` **instance** for the class `SomeJavaClass`.

There is an example for convert **Scala** `Function` to **Java** `Function`:

`Foo` functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Foo<T> { // Define a Java FunctionalInterface
    T apply(T t);
}
```

`Bar` class that accept `Foo` function as parameter:

```
public class Bar<T> {
    public Bar(Foo<T> foo)
}
```

So in **Scala**, we can pass **Scala** `Function` to **Java** `class` by:

```
class B(c: String => String) extends A((t: String) => c.apply(t)) // convert c of Scala Function to Java Function
val s: String => String = s => s.toUpperCase
val b = new B(s)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "In the above code: (t: T) => p.apply(t), Creat a new SerializablePredicate<T> Java FunctionalInterface instance for the class SomeJavaClass", could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Since `SerializablePredicate` is a SAM (single abstract method) interface, in Scala 2.12 you can just write

```
new SomeJavaClass(x => ...)
```

and the lambda will be compiled into a `SerializablePredicate`. If you need to support older Scala versions, you can create an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def makeSerializable[A](p: A => Boolean): SerializablePredicate[A] = new SerializablePredicate[A] {
  def test(x: A) = p(x) // or whatever Predicate's method is called
}
```

and whenever it's in scope, you can pass a lambda to methods/classes which take `SerializablePredicate`.

Note that in both cases you have to ensure the lambda is *actually* serializable, i.e. doesn't capture any non-serializable objects.

Comment: Any idea how you would delegate to a Java method that returns void?

Comment: The Scala equivalent of `void` is `Unit`, except it's a real type.